# Very Low dropout voltage regulator

Tags: ldo

I am using AMS1117 to get 3.3V and my load current is 500mA. The input voltage is 4.1V, but I getting 2.3V instead of 3.3 and that's because of low input voltage which should be in the range of 4.75V and above.

I am unable to find any which works at 4.1V and outputs 3.3V with load of 500mA.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Forget low dropout.  Go for DC to DC converter.

Comment: It will be expensive.

Comment: TI's search engine shows 157 LDOs that would work.  Here's one: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp5912.pdf

Comment: @JohnD How about variation in voltage drop when load current will be high?

Comment: The list has also mentioned LM1117 which won't work because as mentioned in data sheet `LM1117-3.3
0≤IOUT ≤800mA,4.75V≤VIN ≤ 10 V`

Comment: My suggestion would be to get on a distributor search and selected the lowest dropout on the list and go with that regulator. If you can't find one in the voltage that you want, then use an adjustable regulator.

Comment: @JohnD ....what a stunning device (LP5912), and with a dropout voltage of 3.55 V  maximum for 3.3 V output voltage.

Comment: This is a shopping question. The LM1117 is an ancient device. It was great when it came out, but is now basically obsolete. It is an OK linear regulator, but really should not be considered a low dropout regulator by today's standards.

Comment: What is the problem? 1117 is not a LDO! There are LDOs with 42 mA dropout at 500mA. See ADM7170ACPZ-3.3-R7 at DigiKey. Even 16mV @500mA are there.

Comment: @AliChen don't you mean 42mV dropout?

Comment: An LDO will have 3.3/4.1 = 80% efficiency. If the "4.1" is really a lithium ion battery, then the average efficiency is more like 3.3/3.7 = 89% efficiency. Might not be worth it for a DC-DC.

Comment: @mkeith No the source voltage is not battery, but a SMPS which somehow has 4.1V voltage output, can't change that.

Comment: So an LDO will give you 80% efficiency then. To me, it is questionable whether it is worthwhile to use a DC-DC. The LDO is already pretty efficient and will be easier and cheaper. You just need a real LDO. There are hundreds of them that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1) 94% efficient TLV62568

[image]

- 2) Lowest cost 92% Buck http://www.ti.com/product/LM3671
- **3) LDO solution   Best bet. $0.09983    (4k) 
  AP2114H-3.3 Diodes Incorporated**

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/AP2114H-3.3TRG1/AP2114H-3.3TRG1DITR-ND/4470756

```
- TO-252-2 90  °C/W
- TO-263-3 73  °C/W  

0.8V drop from 4.1V @0.5A= 0.4W  choose TO-263-3 if no heatsink.
thus 92% efficient.
```

Comment: When going through the data sheet of LDO you mentioned above, I found these parameters :- `VIN =4.3V, 1mA ≤ IOUT ≤ 30mA` `VOUT ×98.5%< 3.3 <VOUT ×101.5%` and I don't think it will work at 4.1V input voltage

Comment: Voltage - Dropout (Typical)  Dropout Voltage V DROP I OUT =1A 450typ 750 mV max

Comment: A switching regulator will likely cost at least twice the price of an LDO linear. The cost of the inductor is very high. I wouldn't consider switching unless there was some overriding low power requirement in the design.

Comment: the graph at 4.3V is just to show idle current , temp rise and load regulation.

Comment: your only concern is thermal resistance.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 No not the graph, but the parameters were under the electrical characteristics on page 12, have a look.

Comment: No,  what do you understand about the dropout spec for a fixed 3.3V out?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 it means for 3.3V, if the Dropout is 0.45V , then the minimum input voltage should be 3.3+0.45 = 3.75V. This is the minimum voltage in which the LDO starts outputting 3.3Volts.

Comment: correct  ,  the other specs use a std Vin of 4.3

Comment: Okay I understand, those are the test conditions?

Comment: yes, your only concern is thermal resistance to keep it cool.

Comment: @AnujMattóõ If you understand everything better about LDO, what was the purpose of your question then?

Comment: If you use distributor search results, you can filter by parameters  and then sort such as by Vdropout, but your next issue is total Rth < 50'C/W